# django Signal request_finished

Tags: django, signals

I am working with django signal and wish to have a handler for `request_finished` signal perform certain operation only when a given http request is made. Any idea on how to do this? I had thought I could use the `WSGIHandler` which is the sender for this signal but not able to process the request parameters from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get request instance in `request_finished` signal, because according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#request-finished) the only argument that is sent with this signal is `sender`

```
sender
The handler class – e.g. django.core.handlers.wsgi.WsgiHandler – that handled the request.
```

Note that in sender you receive a class of sender, not an instance.

You can write [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) with `process_response()` method in order to be able to check request options, like this:

```python
class MyCustomMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.something == 'something':
            # do something
        return None
```

Then put `MyCustomMiddleware` in [MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) in settings file. Position doesn't matter in that case, because in response cycle request already formed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually found a work around. I do agree with your idea on having a custom MIDDLEWARE.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I ask myself why the signal handler does not get the request object.